# только начала изучать js. как можно создать кнопку ,при клике на которую будет каждый раз выдаваться новое слово?

Tags: javascript

как можно создать кнопку ,при клике на которую будет каждый раз выдаваться новое слово?

Comment: что вы понимаете под "выдаваться новое слово"? Слово из определенного набора? Если да, то случайное слово из набора или в каком-то порядке? "Выдаваться" куда? Конкретизируйте свой вопрос, иначе он, скорее всего, будет закрыт

Answer (score 3):

```html
<button onclick="alert(Math.random().toString(36).substring(7))">Кнопка</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

По клику на кнопку в HTML выводит результат случайного слова, на примере массива.

1. в var randomWords создаем массив и помещаем туда слова.
2. в var randomWord получаем случайное слово из нашего созданного массива
3. в var randomInsult = присваиваем результат нашего случайного слова.
4. выводим результат.

   ```js
   document.getElementById('moo').addEventListener('click',function(){

   var randomWords = ["слово1","слово2","слово3","слово4","слово5"];
   var randomWord = randomWords [Math.floor(Math.random() * randomWords.length)];


   var randomInsult =  [randomWord];
   randomInsult;  

     document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = randomInsult;
   });
   ```

   ```html
   <button class="btn" id='moo'>Генирировать</button>
   <p class="text" id="result"></p>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
Надо создать функцию , при вызове которой выполняются следуезие действия : 
if(/*проверка элемента на содержимое (слово hello)*/){
    //удалить hello 
    //вставить world 
}else if(/* проверка на содержимое (слово world)*/){
    //удалить world 
    //вставить hello
}; // и так далее
```